# pg_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_select

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bitnami, pg, ruby-c-extension

```
bash-4.2# rake db:create
/opt/rubystack-2.3.1-0/ruby/bin/.ruby.bin: symbol lookup error: /opt/rubystack-2.3.1-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_select
bash-4.2# ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
bash-4.2# rails -v
Rails 4.2.6
bash-4.2# gem list pg

*** LOCAL GEMS ***



  pg (0.18.4, 0.15.1)
```

what's the problem?  it's bitnami's ruby stack.

**NOTE:** It's NOT pg version's bug? Please check my log! **Ruby version 2.3.1, `pg` version 0.18.4.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rb_thread_select` function has been deprecated since Ruby **1.9.3**. It was replaced by the `rb_thread_fd_select` function as of Ruby **2.2**:

```
VA  VD  VR
old 193 22  rb_thread_select -> rb_thread_fd_select
```

However, the `pg` gem [has been using the correct function](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/commit/9f8b1575f7710458b262e91a441a13b2f2eeac0a) since version **0.15**. Here's the relevant section of [`pg_connection.c` @ e5cb1df](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/e5cb1df93c496560444941d7a531e4cd675ec7c2/ext/pg_connection.c):

```c
#ifndef HAVE_RB_THREAD_FD_SELECT
#define rb_fdset_t fd_set
#define rb_fd_init(f)
#define rb_fd_zero(f)  FD_ZERO(f)
#define rb_fd_set(n, f)  FD_SET(n, f)
#define rb_fd_term(f)
#define rb_thread_fd_select rb_thread_select
#endif
```

These directives are evaluated at compile time, so the C extension's shared object must have been compiled incorrectly.

The `HAVE_RB_THREAD_FD_SELECT` macro must not have been defined when `pg_ext.so` was built. This could have happened because:

- It was built against a Ruby that did not have `rb_thread_fd_select`
- It was incorrectly configured during the build process

---

References:

- [Remove deprecated definitions](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9502)
- [CAPI obsolete definitions](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/CAPI_obsolete_definitions)
- [Make use of `rb_thread_fd_select()` on Ruby 1.9, to avoid deprecation warnings on `rb_thread_select()`.](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/commit/9f8b1575f7710458b262e91a441a13b2f2eeac0a)
- [ruby-pg/ext/pg_connection.c](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/e5cb1df93c496560444941d7a531e4cd675ec7c2/ext/pg_connection.c)

Comment: `It was built against a Ruby that did not have rb_thread_fd_select`: Did you mean ,when bundle install ,it point to a bad ruby version?@Matheus Moreira

Comment: @Albert.Qing, if you installed the gem yourself and it built the extension at that time, it is possible that the Ruby the build system checked didn't have the `rb_thread_fd_select` function. So, it probably wasn't the latest version; an older system Ruby perhaps?

Comment: You solved my puzzle,I guess the bitnami's ruby may have problem,thank's @Matheus Moreira

Comment: @Albert.Qing so how did you proceed to make things work? I'm facing the same problem :) #bitnamiFtw