# Rails app deployment: pg_ext.so: Undefined symbol: rb_thread_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, pg

I have a RoR application which I used to deploy to Bluemix using cloud foundry. Up to now this worked fine, however, for a few days I get the following error during the deployment of my app:

```
ruby: symbol lookup error: /tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/pg_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_select
```

I have no idea why this suddenly happens and why the pg gem is using rb_thread_select in version 0.18.4 as I read that this has not been part of the gem since pg 0.15+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pg\_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb\_thread\_select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083480/pg-ext-so-undefined-symbol-rb-thread-select)

Comment: Any resolution here? I'm experiencing the same issue using CloudFoundry and the CloudFoundry Ruby buildpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to Ruby 2.3.1 This worked for me while deploying to CloudFoundry using the CloudFoundry Ruby Buildpack.

Comment: Thanks @luke-keller just recently I have tried the same and it really seems to be a workaround (I don't want to call this a solution :) ). Though, I am not sure if upgrading from 2.2.2 to 2.3.1. could break anything in my application. Therefore I would highly prefer to continue with 2.2.2 and carefully prepare  a migration to 2.3.1. What do you think?

Comment: @Günther that's exactly what I had to do. I had some gem conflicts (particularly with nokogiri) but nothing that couldn't be resolved quickly.

Comment: A detailed explanation one can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083480/pg-ext-so-undefined-symbol-rb-thread-select